# How to select only one option from an array?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I need to know how to pick only one option from an array.I need to make an `@if` for two icons, but in view I receive more informations that I need.
**Controller:**

```
  $categoryID =  \App\Category::pluck('id');

            if($filter == 'all' || $filter == 'news')
            {
                $news = \App\News::with('user','category')->whereHas('user', function($query) {
                        $query->where('deleted_at', '=', null);
                    })->whereIn('category_id',$categoryID)->where(function($query1) use ($id) { $query1->where('public','=', 1)->orWhereHas('user.contact', function ($query2) use ($id) {
                            $query2->where('contacts.user_id', '=', $id);
                            })->orWhere('user_id','=',$id);
                        });


$temp['roleNews'] = $news->user->role;
```

**Code in view:**

```
{{$noticeboard_data['roleNews']}}
```

**And what I receive:**

```
[

 {"id":1,
 "slug":"individuals",
  "name":"Individuals",
  "permissions":"",
  "created_at":null,
  "updated_at":null,
  "pivot":{
    "user_id":"542",
    "role_id":"1"}
  }
]
```

I need to receive only `role_id` of every user because I will use it for something like this:

```
@if($noticeboard_data['roleNews'] == 1)
    <i style="font-size: 15px" class="icon-user"></i> 
                        @elseif($noticeboard_data['roleNews'] == 100)
    <i style="font-size: 15px" class="icon-hotel-restaurant-172 u-line-icon-pro fa- fa-lg"></i>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I missunderstand the problem, but why dont use a key path like following?:

```
$noticeboard_data['roleNews']['pivot']['role_id']
```

Comment: because I receive an error: `Undefined index: role_id`

Comment: @AndreiNagy oh ok what´s about `$noticeboard_data['roleNews'][0]['pivot']['role_id']` it seems there is an array within `$noticeboard_data['roleNews']`

Comment: And how can I use the role in something like this? `@if({{$noticeboard_data['roleNews'][0]['pivot']['role_id']}} == 1)
          <i class="icon-user"></i>
          @else
          <i class="icon-trophy"></i>
          @endif `  ? Because I receive `syntax error, unexpected '<' `

Comment: so actualy I did not use laravel yet but I guess its caused by the braces. So try this `@if($noticeboard_data['roleNews'][0]['pivot']['role_id'] == 1) <i class="icon-user"></i> @else <i class="icon-trophy"></i> @endif` I guess you have to use `{{yourVar}}` within template if you not already in "laravel-template-control-code-mode" XD like you are with `@if...`